# how to check data from 1 multidimensional array in other multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 multidimensional array. First one is `$voucher_menu` will be return to this following array :

this one is print_r :

```
Array
(
[menu_0] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 521
        [qty] => 1
        [choice] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 6
            )

    )

[menu_1] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 525
        [qty] => 2
        [choice] => Array
            (
                [0] => 8
            )

    )

[menu_2] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 520
        [qty] => 3
        [choice] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

And the second one `$item_cart` will return to this following array :

```
Array
(
[menu_0] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 517
        [qty] => 1
        [choice] => Array
            (
                [0] => 11
                [1] => 12
            )

    )

[menu_1] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 525
        [qty] => 1
        [choice] => Array
            (
                [0] => 8
            )

    )

[menu_2] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 521
        [qty] => 2
        [choice] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 6
            )

    )

[menu_3] => Array
    (
        [menu_id] => 520
        [qty] => 3
        [choice] => Array
            (
            )

    )

 )
```

I want trying to validate all data in `$voucher_menu` from the `menu_id`, the value of `qty` and `choice` should be haved in `$item_cart`.

This is my code what i have done :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($voucher_menu);$i++){
    if(count($voucher_menu["menu_".$i]["choice"]) != 0) {
        $variant_menu[] = $voucher_menu["menu_" . $i]["choice"];
    }
}

    $valid = true;
    foreach($voucher_menu as $row){
        $pass = false;
        foreach($item_cart as $value) {
            if ($row["menu_id"] == $value["menu_id"]) {
                if (isset($variant_menu)) {
                    if(count($row["choice"]) > 0) {
                        $variant = in_array($row["choice"], $value["choice"]);

                    }

                }
                if ($variant == true) {
                    $pass = true;
                    break;
                }
                if ($row["qty"] <= $value["qty"]) {
                    $pass = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }


        if(!$pass){
            $valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($valid == true){
        echo "You got your discount";
    }else{
        echo "You dont get any discount";
    }
```

I can validate the `menu_id` and the `qty` of item but i dont know how to validate the `choice`.

I want if in `$voucher_menu` and if the `menu_id` have `choice` and the `array` of choice is not `0`, than the value `choice` should be same in `item_cart`

guys can you help me how to check the `choice`? or if you have the other way to validate data from `$voucher_menu` to `$item_cart` please show me.

thank you (:

p.s the `choice` string is `id` and will be return different `id` if the `menu_id` are different
so if `menu_id` is `521` the `choice` is `1, 6` in other `menu_id` will not `1,6`

Comment: Please re arrange your array in readable format.

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain my array is coming from database, and i got it from `var_dump` how  to re arrange it?

Comment: if you use `print_r` instead of `var_dump` it will more readable i think.

Comment: @Kelvin `echo "<pre>";print_r($array);` will give you proper format..

Comment: i have change it @Md.SahadatHossain

Comment: I always use var_dump(), no problem for me in reading var_dump() output. It doesn't even matter how you read output.

Comment: @Kelvin clear your exact requirement..

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_diff](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or [array_intersect](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

With array_diff you can do the following within your loops:

```
$variant = count(array_diff($row["choice"], $value["choice"])) == 0;
```

You might even experiment with doing an array_diff on the whole array of menus and checking if qty was different, simplifying the code greatly.